# How do I skip wordpress's 404 handling?

Tags: redirect, htaccess, 404-error

I want to extend my website in a way that is parallel to the wordpress theme.

Example:

My website with wordpress is at: `www.mywebsite.com`
By ftp I added a directory named `test`, in which there is a php file `test.php`

The problem is that if I write in the url: `www.mywebsite.com/test/test.php` it redirects me to the "page not found" of my theme.

How can I deactivate this behavior?

Posting .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# # av:php5-engine
AddHandler av-php5 .php

# # av:Toolbar
SetEnv AV_TOOLBAR 1
```

Comment: Check first, permissions of `test` directory, and `test.php` file. They should be **755**, and **644**, respectively. Change them, if they are not. That should fix the problem. If the problem does not go away, edit your question, and include a content of `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Did you add the `test` directory in the document root (eg. `public_html`, `htdocs`, etc.)?

Comment: @MrWhite is in the directory with wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes directories. Is it a problem?

Comment: @FrankP.Walentynowicz I corrected test and test.php but it doesn't work. Editing the question as requested

Comment: Those two RewriteCond lines in your htaccess check if it’s a physical file or directory first before handing off the request to WordPress, what you are describing is not default WordPress behavior.

Comment: @Milo so I need to delete them?

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro: If your website is installed in root of `www.mywebsite.com`, modify your .`htaccess`, by replacing two occurrences of 'mywebsiteBase/' with '' ( empty string ). That's all.

Comment: @FrankP.Walentynowicz I just created a new website with wordpress and it worked. Yet in my real website it's not working...must be my theme that is blocking me in another way

Comment: Do you have any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories? mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default, so any directives in a subdirectory `.htaccess` file could be overriding parent directives. (Just to clarify, the `.htaccess` file you posted initially referenced a subdirectory - was that in error?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native WordPress rules are designed to ignore any existing files and directories, including arbitrary PHP scripts. This is literally what this part of directives mean:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

So under normal circumstances WP just shouldn't be involved with your request in any way. You may have some other rewrite rules interfering, possibly from a different place in web server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you cannot execute 'plain' (non-WP-code) PHP code on a WordPress site. WP will use the URL as a 'pointer' to an entry (page/post) in your WP database. It will not load/run the PHP code in the file.

If you want to have a customized 404 file, then create a child theme and then copy/modify the 404.php file from the parent theme. Lots of googles on how to create child themes (and why they are important).

There are plugins that will allow you to put PHP code in a page/post. But, based on your question, the best solution is a customized 404 template.

** **Edit** **
I stand corrected. A non-WP PHP page can be displayed on a WP-based site. Of course, it doesn't have any of the site's "look" (for which you'd want to use a template with your PHP code), but it does work.

I always thought that it wouldn't, based on some murkily-remembered past experience.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. I do use many non-WordPress scripts, residing within WordPress structure, and none of my websites complains about it.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to change the 404.php behaviour. I just want to create a custom route for my file so that when I type a specific url the custom code I created gets called and not the 404 of wordpress.

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro: WordPress, in its default settings, recognizes URLs ending with a file and its extension. I use them for a long time, to automate many tasks, and I run them from system cron, regularly.

Comment: So how do I do it?

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro: read my last comment to your question.

Comment: Humm..... this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810124/how-to-add-a-php-page-to-wordpress (the second answer) seems to indicate that a non-template type PHP page can be run within WP, but you have do do some 'includes' of WP core in order to do that.  Is that what you did @FrankP.Walentynowicz , or is your PHP page within your WP site 'standalone' (with no WP code, no template, etc)?

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro: no, you don't need anything extra. My structure is: `mywebsite.com/scripts`, where `scripts`, is a directory, holding my non-wordpress `.php` scripts.

Comment: @RickHellewell: sorry, my last comment was for you.

Comment: @RickHellewell the question on stackoverflow, you have referred to, is about page/post templates, not plain php scripts.